# Headers not received in the consumer side application using kafka as a middleware between producer and consumer side

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We have implemented one application to produce messages plus headers and send it to a kafka topic. The consumer side application is listening to that kafka topic. Consumer side app is able to receive the payload but headers are not received.Earlier our headers were received in the payload property. In order to disable the embedding of headers (including contentType) into payload, we have used

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw
```

But we are not able to receive headers in the consumer side application. How can we receive these headers?
We are using **spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka** dependency with version **2.0.1.RELEASE**

Producer properties:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          headers: custom-header, source-timestamp
          configuration:
            key:
              deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
              serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value:
              deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
              serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: customDestination
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            headerMode: raw
```

Consumer properties:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          headers: axon-message-type, source-timestamp
          configuration:
            key:
              deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value:
              deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: customDestination
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            headerMode: raw
```

Answer (score 0):

`HeaderMode.raw` means send no headers; it is deprecated in favor of `none`.

The default is now `HeaderMode.headers`, so either remove the headermode or use `headers`.

Comment: If I remove headermode, all the header fields come as part of message payload itself

Comment: Then you aren't using 2.0.x as you claim. I just tested it with that starter and had no problems.

Comment: Can you post the application.properties/yml file?  We tried with both options -  none and headers, in both cases the headers as embedded in the message payload itself. We are using version 2.0.1.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka in both producer and consumer side applications.

Comment: Just to clarify further, producer and consumer are 2 separate spring boot applications producing and consuming to/from the same topic.

Comment: The issue was due incompatible version of spring-boot-starter and spring cloud. Spring-boot-starter version was 1.5, it worked on updating it to 2.0.4.RELEASE